# Populating an object's properties with an array?

Tags: php

I want to take an array and use that array's values to populate an object's properties using the array's keynames. Like so:

```
$a=array('property1' => 1, 'property2' => 2);
$o=new Obj();
$o->populate($a);

class Obj
{
    function Populate($array)
    {
        //??
    }
}
```

After this, I now have:

```
$o->property1==1
$o->property2==2
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $o->$key = $value;
}
```

However, the syntax you are using to declare your array is not valid. You need to do something like this:

```
$a = array('property1' => 1, 'property2' => 2);
```

If you don't care about the class of the object, you could just do this (giving you an instance of `stdClass`):

```
$o = (Object) $a;
```

Comment: Woops on the array too, that's my new language which is a merge of PHP and python :p

Answer (score -3):

Hm. What about having something like

```
class Obj
{

    var properties = array();

    function Populate($array)
    {
        this->properties = $array;
    }
}
```

Then you can say:

```
$o->properties['property1'] == 1
...
```