# Populating an object's properties

Tags: php, object, associative-array

Consider following code:

```
$ob=new MyObject();

$ob->name=$_GET['name'];
$ob->email=$_GET['email'];
...
$ob->foo=$_GET['foo'];
```

Is there any cleaner way (language mechanism) to populating an object's property with an associative array. (**without using `foreach` or similar constructs**)?

Answer (score 1):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045542/populating-an-objects-properties-with-an-array) answer states, you can do:

```
$ob = (Object) $a;
```

Comment: As that ansewer states "If you don't care about the class of the object...". I care about class of the object!!

Answer (score 0):

Only foreach? You can other loop: while, for. What about goto?

Also you can use some functions without obvious loop.

```
$object = new MyObject();
$array = array('foo' => 1, 'baz' => 2);

array_walk($array, function ($value, $field)use($object){
    $object->$field = $value;
});
```